# How to post a photo from camera to firebase database using android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am developing an application whereby I will take a photo and post it to my Firebase database together with some descriptions. I have written some code, but when I take a photo and click the ok button, the app crashes.

Below is my code:

The error is [view crush error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhqyR.png)

```
    package com.example.user.potholereportingapp;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;
import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;
import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;
import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;
import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;
import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;

public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageButton mSelectImage;
    private EditText mPostTitle;
    private EditText mPostDesc;
    private Button mSubmitBtn;
    private Uri photo=null;
    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;
    static final int CAM_REQUEST=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        mStorage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
        mProgress=new ProgressDialog(this);

        mSelectImage=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageSelect);
        mPostTitle=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.titleField);
        mPostDesc=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.descField);

        mSubmitBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submitBtn);

        mSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CAM_REQUEST);
                }
            }
        });

        mSubmitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startPosting();
            }
        });

    }

    private void startPosting() {

        mProgress.setMessage("Posting Image...");
        mProgress.show();

        final String title_val = mPostTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        final String desc_val = mPostDesc.getText().toString().trim();
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val)&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && photo != null){

            mProgress.show();
            StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Blog_Images").child(photo.getLastPathSegment());

            filepath.putFile(photo).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Uri downloadUrl =taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
                    newPost.child("title").setValue(title_val);
                    newPost.child("desc").setValue(desc_val);
                    newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());

                    mProgress.dismiss();
                     startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                }
            });
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode==CAM_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {

            photo = data.getData();
            mSelectImage.setImageURI(photo);

            CropImage.activity(photo)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(this);
        }
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

                mSelectImage.setImageURI(resultUri);
                photo= resultUri;

            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace.

Comment: @Piyush,I have added a screenshot of the crush error that I get

Comment: Have you added read and write external storage permissions in manifest file ?

Comment: @Piyush,yeah I already have them in my manifest file but as you you noticed am not saving my photo in my external storage but I want to display it in my image button before I post it together with the descriptions to the firebase database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i researched about the problem I had and i came to find out how I can do it.
1.First,i decided to save my photo in my External file.
2.Second,I uploaded the photo from my External file to firebase database.

Below is my code:

```
package com.example.user.potholereportingapp;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;

public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageButton mSelectImage;
    private EditText mPostTitle;
    private EditText mPostDesc;
    private Button mSubmitBtn;
    private String file=null;
    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;
    static final int CAM_REQUEST=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        mStorage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
        mProgress=new ProgressDialog(this);

        mSelectImage=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageSelect);
        mPostTitle=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.titleField);
        mPostDesc=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.descField);

        mSubmitBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submitBtn);

        mSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                Intent camera_intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File file=getFile();
                camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivityForResult(camera_intent,CAM_REQUEST);
            }
        });

        mSubmitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startPosting();
            }
        });

    }
    private File getFile(){
        File folder=new File("sdcard/camera_app");

        if(!folder.exists()){
            folder.mkdir();
        }
        File image_file=new File(folder,"cam_image.jpg");
        return image_file;
    }

    private void startPosting() {

        mProgress.setMessage("Posting Image...");
        mProgress.show();

        final String title_val = mPostTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        final String desc_val = mPostDesc.getText().toString().trim();
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val)&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && file != null){

            mProgress.show();
            StorageReference filepath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("images");

            Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("sdcard/camera_app/"));
            StorageReference riversRef = filepath.child("file"+new Date().getTime());
            UploadTask uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(file);
            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sending failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Uri downloadUrl =taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
                    newPost.child("title").setValue(title_val);
                    newPost.child("desc").setValue(desc_val);
                    newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());

                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this,"Uploading Finished...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                }
            });
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode==CAM_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {

             file="sdcard/camera_app/";
            mSelectImage.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(file));





        }
    }
}
```